# How to query out random company name from grouping MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to get specific company name from grouping. The table data look like this. I want to be able to choose one of the company_name to show in the output depending on my preference. For example i want to show Halliburton, or Hycalog, or Drill in the output for Rig A is that even possible?

```
rig     sequence  company_name  total_time  
------  --------  ------------  ------------
Rig A   1         Hycalog                 20
Rig A   2         Halliburton             20
Rig A   3         Drill                   20
Rig B   4         Conoco                  30
Rig B   5         Total                   30
```

I have tried sub-query and case when all not return the results i wanted. All i wanted is to choose which company to show in the output out of the random company in the original data for example in this case i want to show company_name Drill for Rig A and show company_name Total for Rig B...

Of course if possible i can freely choose which company name i would like to show in the output.

```
SELECT rig, sequence, company_name, SUM(total_time) FROM table A GROUP BY rig;
```

```
rig     sequence  company_name  total_time  
------  --------  ------------  ------------
Rig A   3         Drill                   60
Rig B   5         Total                   60
```

Comment: Not at all sure what you are asking, please edit the question to clarify

Comment: Your SQL query is invalid..

Comment: why invalid please tell me where it went wrong

Comment: *"why invalid please tell me where it went wrong"* SQL-92 and earlier does not permit queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are not named in the GROUP BY clause. For example, this query is illegal in standard SQL-92 because the nonaggregated sequence, company_name columns in the select list does not appear in the GROUP BY:   see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)..

Comment: ... there is a expection on this rule in SQL 1999 which is a optional feature (T301) which is functionally [dependent](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) which the manual is also mentioning.

Comment: Thank you for the comment but all i wanted is a solution -- even if it is wrong show me how to get it correct not...just telling me wrong and thats it. I can do that too easy answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then here is one option using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT rig, sequence, company_name, total_time_sum
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rig ORDER BY RAND()) rn,
        SUM(total_time) OVER (PARTITION BY rig) total_time_sum
    FROM tableA
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image]

### Demo

This will choose a random row from each rig group and display it.

Comment: Thank you this seems to solve the problem.....but i have found a solution by using sub query within...to specifically find the company i wanted...so if the company exist then show the company otherwise if the company doesn't exist then show randomly...so the inner query is just to find this and then make another parent query to call everything...it took me 2 days to figure so crazy

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return the expected output:

```
SELECT rig, sequence, company_name, SummedTotal AS total_time
FROM
(
    SELECT *, 
           SUM(total_time) OVER (PARTITION BY rig) AS SummedTotal, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rig ORDER BY RAND()) Rnum
    FROM TableA
) Q
WHERE Rnum = 1;
```